# Force www. for all URLS & remove trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I'm having issues with my .htaccess URL rewriting rules. I'd like to remove trailing slashes and force a www. on all URLs. Here's the .htaccess I have...what's happening is that trailing slash removal only works on www. URL's and that non-home page URLs aren't getting a forced www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force www and remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http%1://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: For some reason this triggered a redirect loop

Comment: Strange since I had tested this. Do you have any other rule in your .htaccess? Also try it in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.